# Yii2 - Custom Pagination

Tags: yii, yii2

What is the right way to have variable pagination in Yii2? 
I mean by this, that I want the user to be able to give the number of items in a page while sending an API request.

I know about setting the `pageSize` in the `dataProvider`.

```
$dataProvider = new SqlDataProvider([
    'sql' => 'SELECT * FROM user WHERE status=:status',
    'params' => [':status' => 1],
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 20,
    ],
]);
```

But my question is about anything that is built in that allows the user to send the pageSize through the request? Is there anything built-in to perform this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave empty the `pagination` field in the dataProvider and just add the `per-page` GET parameter in your calls:

`http://your_url/controlller/action?per-page=20`

More info [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-pagination.html#$pageParam-detail).